# PHP - Laravel Corcel configuration issue with WP database

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

The Laravel log file reports an error with the configuration. I am configuring the WP database in the `.env` as being pointed out in the [official docs](https://github.com/corcel/corcel).

The error I got in the Laravel logs:

> [2019-08-06 10:23:44] local.ERROR: Database [corcel] not configured.
>   {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Database
>   [corcel] not configured. at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:152)

In the `config/database.php` I have a separate connection for Corcel:

```
'corcel' => [ // for WordPress database (used by Corcel)
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database'  => env('DB_WP_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => 'wp_',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ],
```

...and in the config/corcel.php file I have this line:

```
'connection' => 'corcel',
```

...that corresponds to the connection added in `config/database.php`

The configuration in the `.env` file I added the WordPress database which should be the source for Corcel:

```
DB_WP_DATABASE=my_wp_database
```

The rest of the `.env` file is the same and I still got no idea why is this throwing config error.

Answer (score 0):

Your config may be cached, could you try running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Is the error happening when you are trying access data? If so you need to specify the connection on your query.

```
DB::connection('corcel')->table('table_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, you may need to use `unix_socket`. In that case you can include `unix_socket` on the database config like,

```
'corcel' => [ 
            .....
           'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            .....
        ],
```

On the environment variable(`.env` file), you may need to use the following,

```
DB_SOCKET="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```